# .hbs files strips javascript

Tags: gruntjs, handlebars.js, assemble

I am including a script in .hbs file, but every time I assemble grunt assemble this .hbs file, the hbs template inside the script is ignored in the HTML output.
This is my .hbs file

```
<script id="myTemplate1" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
{{#each}}
<div class="sample">
....
</div>
{{/each}}
</script>
```

I assembling the above .hbs file using grunt assemble and it just ignores all the content inside the script tag and I could see only the following in the HTML output

```
<script id="myTemplate1" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
</script>
```

What's wrong here? I tried to have the script as a separate JS file but didn't work? I also tried to include the script in the HTML output but every time I assemble, it overwrites and I get only the empty  tags.

Answer (score 0):

The `#each` block helper requires an array passed to it to iterate over. It would look something like...

```
<script id="myTemplate1" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
{{#each templatesArray}}
<div class="sample">
....
</div>
{{/each}}
</script>
```

See the [Handlebars Documetation](http://handlebarsjs.com/builtin_helpers.html) for more examples.

You should also check out [Handlebars-Helpers](https://github.com/assemble/handlebars-helpers), made by the creators of Assemble, it contains a whole bunch of useful helpers.